# I am building Android (Java) netflix clone using tmdb API service but i got null response

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have got a problem, when I call API its gives null in my app but works fine with postman  below is my `model.wrapper` and `viewmodel` class, and I am using retrofit for API call

```
 public class Episodesresponse {
    
        private List<Episodemodel> episodes;
    
        public List<Episodemodel> getEpisodes() {
            return episodes;
        }
    }
```

above is episode wrapper class.

Episode model class

```
    public class Episodemodel {

    @SerializedName("episode_number")
    int epino;

    @SerializedName("name")
    String name;

    @SerializedName("overview")
    String  overview;

    @SerializedName("still_path")
    String image;

    public int getEpino() {
        return epino;
    }

    public void setEpino(int epino) {
        this.epino = epino;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getOverview() {
        return overview;
    }

    public void setOverview(String overview) {
        this.overview = overview;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Here is `viewmodel` class code:

```
public void fetchEpisodes(int id) {

    Call<Episodesresponse>call = movieapiservice.getEpisodes();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Episodesresponse>() {

        public void onResponse(Call<Episodesresponse>call, Response<Episodesresponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Episodesresponse data =  response.body();
                List<Episodemodel> datalist=data.getEpisodes();


                if(data.getEpisodes()==null)
                    Log.e("#","Episode under sucessful-->" + "null");



            }
            Log.e("#","Episode under response");
        }



        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Episodesresponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("#","Episode under failure "+ t.getMessage());
        }

    });
}
```

service class

```
 @Headers({"Authorization: Bearer "+Apikey.skey, "accept: application/json"})
    @GET("tv/1399?api_key=dewdewfdef78trt43weg&append_to_response=season/2")
    Call<Episodesresponse> getEpisodes();
```

// api key is secret

JSON sample

```
{
 "_id": "5256c89f19c2956ff6046d47",
        "air_date": "2011-04-17",
  "episodes": [
    {
      "episode_number": 1,
      "name": "Episode 1",
      "overview": "This is the first episode.",
      "still_path": "path/to/image.jpg"
    },
    {
      "episode_number": 2,
      "name": "Episode 2",
      "overview": "This is the second episode.",
      "still_path": "path/to/image.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

i am not able to get any response,

Comment: Please add your API `BASE_URL`